# HSQLDB .net API: Method 'getParentLogger' does not have an implementation

Tags: asp.net, hsqldb

I tried to connect to HSQLDB using the API from the official repository but it give me this error:
**System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233054
  Message=Method 'getParentLogger' in type 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver' from assembly 'Org.Hsqldb, Version=1.8.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=05732303801b208f' does not have an implementation.
  Source=
  TypeName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver**
I use Manage NuGet Packages of Visual Studio 2013 to install IKVM and IKVM.OpenJDK.JDBC.
I also add Org.Hsqldb.dll to the reference.
Here are the connection codes:

public class HSQLDBConnection : IConnection 
{

```
private Connection _connection;

public HSQLDBConnection(string dbName, string tableName)
{
    try
    {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
        _connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:" + dbName, "SA", "");
        CreateTable(tableName);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

private int CreateTable(string tableName)
{
    string command = "";
    command += "CREATE TABLE ";
    command += tableName + " (";
    command += "id VARCHAR(255),";
    command += "data LONGVARCHAR,";
    command += "expires_at INTEGER";
    command += ")";
    return _connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(command);
}
```

}

The syntax look like java because this API support java code for HSQLDB. Those codes are written on .net 4.5.

Comment: I think you need to use the Java and Microsoft software versions that were used to develop the HSQLDB .NET package. Those versions are a few years older than 2013.

Comment: Thanks! I tried changing IKVM version and it worked.